# SharePoint 2010 Survey View

Tags: sharepoint

I need to add an ability for users to add custom views for a Survey List. Using Designer is not an option.

In order to add a new View I now open the standard SharePoint form "/_layouts/ViewNew.aspx?List={SurveyListID}".
I setup a new view selecting the fields I want to see. Then, when I look at this View it looks like standard "{SurveyTitle}/overview.aspx" view no matter what I do. But I need it to look more like a SharePoint list view. I've seen dozens blog posts where people used this method and no one mentioned any problems like I am having. I've tried this method using 3 different SharePoint farms and I get the same behavior.

I was able to create a view that works OK using Designer by copying "All Responses" View and editing . However, forcing users to use Designer is not a great idea.

Does anyone know an easy method to force my custom views to display properly in Survey List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally, I've found solution.**

1. Open the page /_layouts/ViewType.aspx?List={SurveyListID}
2. Create a view based on "All Responses" View
3. Done! No need to use Designer